# Vim n key for "partial" word search?

Tags: vim

If I have a C++ function implemented like so in the source file:

```
void ClassName::foo ()
{
   if ( true)
   {
      while ( true )
      {
         fork ();
         1 / 0;
      }
      foo ();
   }
}
```

And I put my cursor on the 3rd last line `foo ()` and press <kbd>*</kbd>, it complains "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP". In other words:

```
/\<foo\>
```

does not match

```
ClassName::foo
```

Is there anyway to override the default search functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your `'iskeyword'` setting for C++ files includes the `:` character. A `*` command on the `ClassName::foo` identifier would highlight the entire identifier.

You can either use the `g*` command (which doesn't enforce the *whole word* search, but would also match in e.g. `pfooey`), or change the option via

```
:setlocal iskeyword-=:
```

(But note that this has consequences for motions like `w`, and potentially even disrupts syntax highlighting.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with `g*`

Comment: Note that without changing `iskeyword`, it will still be impossible to search for `foo` via `g*` or `g#` from within a larger keyword like `ClassName::foo`. Also, `gd` and `gD` will always search with the whole keyword restriction, even if you do something like `nnoremap * g*` and `nnoremap g* *`.

Comment: @NikitaKouevda brings up a valid restriction; you can use my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) or some of the other resources listed on its page to extend the `*` command to the visual selection. That lets you search for arbitrary strings from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `wrapscan` option is on by default so you should get the same message with the cursor jumping to the `foo` in `ClassName::foo`, as expected.

Do `:verbose set wrapscan?` to see where the default value was changed.

Also, you mention `n` in the title but not in the body, what?

Comment: Without `wrapscan` on, Vim wouldn't say `search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP`, as described in the question.